# Python3のインタラクティブシェル上での補完を有効にする

Tags: python

Python3のインタラクティブシェル上で補完を有効にしたいのですが、どうすればいいのでしょうか?
Ctrl-nで補完がしたいのですが、PYTHONSTARTUPで指定したファイルに

```
import readline
import rlcompleter

readline.parse_and_bind("\C-n: complete")
```

としてもインタラクティブシェル上で補完されせん。

OSはOS X Yosemiteです。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3.4 では、 readline が利用可能であれば、 PYTHONSTARTUP を使わなくてもデフォルトで補完機能が有効になっています。

しかし、 Mac ではシステムが持ってる readline が GNU readline ではなく libedit になっている関係で、標準ライブラリの readline が機能しません。

Python のインストール方法を問わず利用できる方法として、 Python が持っているインタラクティブシェルよりも高機能な ipython を利用する手があります。

Python 本体のインタラクティブシェルの補完機能を有効にしたい場合は、 Python のインストール方法ごとに、以下のような手段があります。

### Homebrew

`brew install python3` する前に `brew install readline` しておけば、 GNU readline が使われます。

### MacPorts

`ports install py34-readline` で GNU readline が利用できます。

### pyenv

Homebrew で readline をインストールしてあれば、自動的にそれが利用されます。

### その他

IPython が利用してる方法で、標準ライブラリの readline と別に GNU の readline をインストールしてそれを使うことができます。

`pip install gnureadline` しておいて、 PYTHONSTARTUP で指定するファイルに次のように書いておきます。 (readline ではなく gnureadline モジュールを利用していることに注意)

```
import gnureadline
import rlcompleter
gnureadline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
```

Answer (score 1):

補完機能を充実させたい場合には標準の対話シェルの代わりにIPythonを使うのも手です。homebrewでpython3をインストール(場合によってはpyenvを導入)して`pip install ipython`すればインストール補完が有効な状態で使えます。